# Tensorflow SavedModel file size increases with each save

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a Tensorflow R1.13 training code that saves a SavedModel periodically during a long training run (I am following this excellent [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-tensorflow-models-to-production-using-tf-serving-4b4b78d41700) on the topic).  I have noticed that each time the model is saved the size increases.  In fact it seems that it increases exactly linearly each time, and seems to be a multiple of the initial file size.  I wonder if TF is keeping a reference to all previous saved files and accumulating them for each later save.  Below are the file sizes for several SavedModel files written in sequence over time, as training progresses.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  576962 Apr 15 23:56 ./model_accuracy_0.361/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1116716 Apr 15 23:58 ./model_accuracy_0.539/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1656470 Apr 16 00:11 ./model_accuracy_0.811/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2196440 Apr 16 00:15 ./model_accuracy_0.819/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2736794 Apr 16 00:17 ./model_accuracy_0.886/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3277150 Apr 16 00:19 ./model_accuracy_0.908/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3817530 Apr 16 00:21 ./model_accuracy_0.919/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4357950 Apr 16 00:25 ./model_accuracy_0.930/saved_model.pb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4898492 Apr 16 00:27 ./model_accuracy_0.937/saved_model.pb
```

Is there a way to cull out the previous saved versions?  Or at least prevent them from being accumulated in the first place?  I will certainly only keep the last file, but it seems to be 10x larger than it should be.

Below is my code (largely copied from [Silva](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-tensorflow-models-to-production-using-tf-serving-4b4b78d41700)):

```
        # Creates the TensorInfo protobuf objects that encapsulates the input/output tensors
        tensor_info_input_data_1 = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(gd.data_1)
        tensor_info_input_data_2 = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(gd.data_2)
        tensor_info_input_keep   = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(gd.keep  )

        # output tensor info
        tensor_info_output_pred = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(gd.targ_pred_oneh)
        tensor_info_output_soft = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(gd.targ_pred_soft)

        # Define the SignatureDef for this export
        prediction_signature = \
            tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
                inputs={
                    'data_1': tensor_info_input_data_1,
                    'data_2': tensor_info_input_data_2,
                    'keep'  : tensor_info_input_keep
                },
                outputs={
                    'pred_orig': tensor_info_output_pred,
                    'pred_soft': tensor_info_output_soft
                },
                method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)

        graph_entry_point_name = "my_model" # The logical name for the model in TF Serving

        try:
            builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(saved_model_path)
            builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                sess= sess,
                tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                signature_def_map = {graph_entry_point_name:prediction_signature}
            )
            builder.save(as_text=False)
            if verbose:
                print("  SavedModel graph written successfully. " )
            success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print("       WARNING::SavedModel write FAILED. " )
            traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
            success = False
        return success
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hephaestus,

If you're constructing a `SavedModelBuilder` each time, then it'll add new save operations to the graph every time you `save`.

Instead, you can construct `SavedModelBuilder` only once and just call `builder.save` repeatedly. This will not add new ops to the graph on each `save` call.

Alternatively I think you can create your own `tf.train.Saver` and pass it to `add_meta_graph_and_variables`. Then it shouldn't create any new operations.

A good debugging aid is `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` once you're done graph building, which will throw an exception rather than expanding the graph like this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  The implicit graph construction can be so counter-intuitive. I will test this in a week or so and reply with the results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set clear_extraneous_saver = True for Saver

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b78d23cf92656db63bca1f2cbc9636c7caa387ca/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py#L382

meta_graph_def = saver.export_meta_graph(
       clear_devices=clear_devices, clear_extraneous_savers=True, strip_default_attrs=strip_default_attrs)